# Is it possible to do this kind of locking with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We have this web service with the following algorithm (the input is an id and a name)

```
public bool SetCustomer(int externalId,string name)
{           
    using (var db = new BusinessEntities())          
    {      
        var c = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(c => c.externalId== externalId) ?? new Customer(){externalId = externalId};
        c.name =  name;
        db.SaveChanges();     
    }
}
```

The problem is, if someone calls at the same moment this web service with the same id, then 2 customers are created.

We cannot add a unique constraint, because some other process in the app might create customer with the same externalId.

We thought about a solution with a dictionary of object that would be used as lock argument, but it doesn't seems right.

We don't want to lock the full table customer because we have a lot of parallel calls, so this will cause timeout.

Comment: You can handle in your webservice a registration of the ID in an Observable collection, register to the CollectionChanged event, check the ID and stop the process.

Comment: Just let the database handle locks, what is externalID for? the database should handle IDs not external calls that is a recipe for disaster

Comment: what about handling a source column ? 'W' for web service, and 'O' for others. Then add a unique constraint on (ExternalId, Source) ?

Comment: @tschmit007 there could be double rows with O and '1' (depending on the source, we have or don't have to check the unicity)

Comment: @MarkHomer as you can see on the code, the id is external, our partners doesn't know about our ids, just theirs (we also have an identity column on customer)

Comment: @StefanoBafaro can you elaborate ? do you have a blog post or something illustrating this ?

Comment: @remibourgarel Unfortunately I don't know an online example. Basically an ObservableCollection ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx ) give you the chance to handle the CollectionChanged Event ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx ) and you can Intercept when anyone try to register any ID.

Comment: I dont understand this, if you have muliple entries with same external id, you update one of them with the name - but you dont know wich one...?

Comment: My code is a web service (so multi threaded), if 4 calls arrives in the mean time with the same informations, then 4 rows with the same information will be added to the db (because when they try to check for the externalid, it doesn't exists yet)

Comment: Can you register somewhere in your class these ID _before_ sending them directly to the DB?

Comment: I get the problem with multiple inserts, but it looks like you update the database if the external id already exists with a new name.

Comment: for the client using this web service the external id is supposed to be unique, but it's not the case all the time (and I don't want to get an exception, i just want people to wait in line if there is already an existing external id)

Comment: Depending on the load you could try to put the code inside a TransactionScope with IsolationLevel =Serializable

Comment: @remibourgarel your partners don't need to know your ids, and if they do why cant you return it to them after creation?

Comment: @DanielStackenland this app and the db are already under huge load

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an intermediate table to log insertion jobs.

Then do the jobs (creating the customer) with a mono threaded task.

This may require an asynchronous solution if your web method has to return a result.

Or even something more elaborated like Asynchronous Triggers from [Sql Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166071%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Comment: that would work, but if the client receive a 200 status response, that won't mean the row is inserted, so, in some way I'm breaking the interface definition

Comment: that is why you need some asynchronous technology, may be signalR ?

Answer (score 0):

I found something :

http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/

it's not with entity framework but I don't think EF provide access to this kind of features.

thanks